# Add forced login functionality in x-cart

Tags: php, x-cart

I have a store created on X-Cart, and I want to add a functionality so the user's must login on a customer login before seeing any site contents/products. If user is not logged in she/he must be redirected to the login page.

Comment: What version of X-Cart is there? There are X-Cart 4 and X-Cart 5 which differ from each other a lot so the solution will be different.

Comment: It is X-cart 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In X-Cart 5 you can use "memberships" http://kb.x-cart.com/en/users/user_membership_levels.html to setup products as accessible by users with certain membership. So they will have to log in 1st to be able to see products configured to be accessible for certain membership customers.

Comment: That is somewhat helpful. But it still doesn't restrict user's to see the content before logging in.

Comment: If you put all content in products it will work. Generic pages are not possible to hide without customizing X-Cart I fear.